# Does a chipped glass corner/edge compromise integrity on a rimless aquarium cover?

Tags: aquarium

I received a rimless aquarium and lid that were damaged in shipping.  The lid was chipped on the very corner, and I'm working on a resolution with the seller.

My understanding is that some glass (tempered?) is specifically very strong on the face and very fragile on the edges.  This tank is advertised as "91% clarity Diamant glass", and since the chip is on a corner where it affects the side and the face I'm unsure if I should be concerned about it being beyond cosmetic.  It being a cover that doesn't constantly contact the water I expect it will have daily temperature changes (whereas the rest of the tank should see much less due to water's thermal capacitance and the tank's temperature control).

Should I be concerned that the chipped corner on this lid could randomly shatter, or is it likely to be superficial damage and something I can work with the seller on addressing short of replacement?

Here's a photo--the chip is approximately 1/2" long on the longest side, and 1/16" deep (perhaps 20% of the overall thickness of the glass).
[image: chipped aquarium cover]

Comment: From your descriptiom I can not imagine how this lid is used. Maybe you could add another picture, showing the lid "in use"? My firat thought would be, that it should not effect the whole lid, but depends for ex. on wich parts the weight would lay on

Comment: i do not dare to give you an answer about the safety of your glass but i think you should get the damaged part of the corner removed so you get a clean surface.

Comment: It's most likely fine as long as you don't see runners in the glass and you aren't putting weight on it. I've seen bigger chips in rimless aquariums and they were fine with water in them. This being a lid, it's unlikely for it to catastrophically shatter, but it's still possible so you should decide whether it's worth the risk. To me the biggest risk would be getting cut on it.